# Referencing a ghcr.io image in a Docker-based Github action

Tags: docker, github-actions, ghcr

I have a Docker container Github action that relies on a base image hosted in ghcr.io. The github repo for the action also hosts this docker image as a github package. The Dockerfile used by my action looks like this:

```
FROM ghcr.io/ourcorp-actions/my-action-image:latest

COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

...and my `action.yaml` simply references this `Dockerfile`:

```yaml
name: Some Action
author: Our Team
description: Some Description

runs:
  using: docker
  image: Dockerfile
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work when invoked:

```
  #0 building with "default" instance using docker driver
  
  #1 [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile
  #1 transferring dockerfile: 167B done
  #1 DONE 0.0s
  
  #2 [internal] load .dockerignore
  #2 transferring context: 2B done
  #2 DONE 0.1s
  
  #3 [internal] load metadata for ghcr.io/ourcorp-actions/my-action-image:latest
  #3 ERROR: failed to authorize: failed to fetch anonymous token: unexpected status from GET request to https://ghcr.io/token?scope=repository%3Aourcorp-actions%2Fmy-action-image%3Apull&service=ghcr.io: 401 Unauthorized
  ------
   > [internal] load metadata for ghcr.io/gdcorp-actions/switchboard-cache-fallback:latest:
  ------
  Dockerfile:1
  --------------------
     1 | >>> FROM ghcr.io/gdcorp-actions/switchboard-cache-fallback:latest
     2 |     
     3 |     COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
  --------------------
  ERROR: failed to solve: failed to fetch anonymous token: unexpected status from GET request to https://ghcr.io/token?scope=repository%3Agdcorp-actions%2Fswitchboard-cache-fallback%3Apull&service=ghcr.io: 401 Unauthorized
```

It appears that the Docker action is not automatically logged in to pull the base image from ghcr.io. I don't want users of this action to have to manually log into ghcr.io just to run this action; the action should encapsulate the Dockerfile, and the caller shouldn't have to know any of these Docker details.

Is there any way for a Docker-based github action to be able to automatically pull images from ghcr.io?

Comment: Apparently, that base image is not publicly available so the unauthorized error is expected. To work with a private one, you need a PAT. See [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/packages/working-with-a-github-packages-registry/working-with-the-container-registry#authenticating-to-the-container-registry).

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have access to a `private GHCR Image`. You should generate `CR_PAT (container registry personal access token)` if you are able to use the private image from GHCR.

After this procedure is complete. You ought to use your github username when converting to base64.

Once, this step has also been completed place the created token inside
~/.aws/config.json file.

```
{
    "auths": {
        "ghcr.io": {
            "auth": "GENERATED_TOKEN"
        },
    },
    "credsStore": "desktop",
    "currentContext": "desktop-linux"
}
```

Reference, [Github GHCR (Access Private Image)](https://github.com/docker/buildx/discussions/1227#discussioncomment-8839121)